# #div1-x that leads to corresponding operations on #div2-x where x=[a-z]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a glossary menu that contains each letter of the alphabet. So, when you click say, the letter G, you only see glossary entries that start with the letter G. I have a working implementation of this, but I want to make it simpler than writing 26 onclick handlers (one for each letter).

Basically I want to reduce:

```
    $('#nav-a').click(function() {
        $('.glossary-alphabet').not("#glossary-a").hide();
        $("#glossary-a").show();
    });
    $('#nav-b').click(function() {
        $('.glossary-alphabet').not("#glossary-b").hide();
        $("#glossary-b").show();
    });
    $('#nav-c').click(function() {
        $('.glossary-alphabet').not("#glossary-c").hide();
        $("#glossary-c").show();
    }); 
...
```

To something like (pseudocode):

```
    $('#nav-[a-z]').click(function() {
        $('.glossary-alphabet').not("#glossary-[a-z]").hide();
        $("#glossary-[a-z]").show();
    });
```

Is there a way to do this? I know you can use regular expression matching to return all the divs that start with `#nav-`, but how do I set up the regex logic so that each `#nav-X` leads to a corresponding operation on `#glossary-X`?

Comment: In situations like this it's normally better practice to use common classes on the elements, and traverse the DOM to find their relation. If you can add your HTML to the question I can give you a workable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be better to change your HTML so you don't have #nav-a, #nav-b.. similarly to what realseanp suggested, but if you must use your current HTML then something like this should work, I haven't tested the code. Bind the click event to all elements that have an id that starts with "nav-". Then get the last character of the element's id, which will be the letter you want to show.

```
$( "[id^='nav-']" ).click(function(){
    clicked_letter = $(this).attr('id').slice(-1);
    $('.glossary-alphabet').not("#glossary-" + clicked_letter).hide();
    $("#glossary-" + clicked_letter).show();
})
```

Comment: will fail if get to numbers higher than 9 ... might be better to split at `"-"`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="nav-item" data-letter="a">A</div>
<div class="nav-item" data-letter="b">B</div>

<div class="glossary-item" id="glossary-a"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.glossary-item{
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.nav-item').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var letter = $(this).data('letter');
    $('#glossary-' + letter).show();
    $('.glossary-item').not('#glossary-' + letter).hide();
});
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ofojwvqj/1/)